# Has anyone on Earth ever seen the dark side of the moon and if so where are the pictures?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, solar-system, moon, tidal-effect

If the Moon rotates then we should see the dark side right?  But as far as I know the Moon only shows one side to Earth, how can this be if it is rotating?

Comment: There is no "dark side" all the moon gets illuminated over the course of a month.

Comment: Yeah, what dmckee said. Did you mean the far side?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25437/2451

Comment: Yes, I have the P.U.L.S.E DVD, so I can see (and listen to) it any time I want.

Comment: "There is no dark side of the moon, really. Matter of fact, it's all dark."

Comment: More seriously, yes, in fact it is often visible from Earth near dawn or sunset, when the moon is crescent. I presume it is illuminated by Earth shine. Being dark it is hard to photograph.  A nice picture can be found at http://frozensouth.com/2008/10/13/t3-syndrome.aspx .

Answer (score 3):

The rotation of the moon is in synch with its orbit around earth in such a way as to always face earth with the same side. This phenomenon is called [tidal locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_locking). The side facing away from earth is usually called the far side of the moon. It was photographed by Soviet spacecrafts in the 50s and 60s and later observed directly by the crews of a few of the Apollo missions. More details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_side_of_the_Moon#Exploration).

Comment: How did any Apollo missions to the moon *not* see the far side of the moon?

Comment: @DJohnM Quite a few of the first missions were unmanned, some only went into Earth orbit and one crew was killed during launch rehearsal.